# Can you redirect to a Custom Object List Page from a Controller?

Tags: visualforce, redirect

I want to redirect from a visualforce page to a custom obect's list page.  I need to run a method in the controller as th action for the button, so I would like to redirect from the controller.

I found this doc on how [this doc on how to redirect to a standard object list page](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_quick_start_override_list_page.htm), but I need to redirect to a 'Custom Object's List Page', and I need to do it from a controller, not the VF page itself.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could get the object prefix, which returns the first 3 characters in the object's ID.  Then construct an URL and redirect to it.

Create this method:

```
public static PageReference listView(Schema.sObjectType destinationSObject) {
   Schema.DescribeSObjectResult destination = destinationSObject.getDescribe();
   PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/' + destination.getKeyPrefix() );
   pageRef.setRedirect(true);
   return pageRef;
    }
```

Call this method:

```
// Redirect to the Account List View
return listView(Account.sObjectType); 

// Redirect to Some Custom Object's List View
return listView(Some_Custom_Object__c.sObjectType);
```

If you need to get to the landing page append a `/o` after the result.getKeyPrefix():

```
PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/' + result.getKeyPrefix() + '/o');
```

Comment: result.getKeyPrefix() is actually a tighter solution than my String/Substring snippet... Great answer. (If only I hadn't spent all that time on screenshots!)

Answer (score 3):

You can link to the "tab" style page (I figure this is the list page you are asking about) by redirecting to the *first three characters* of the record ID... as this represents the object type.

As you can see here the ID of my custom test object....

[image: object page]

The first three characters is the list page URL

[image: list page]

So if you had a page, with a custom controller, with an object in it, stick a button on the VF page that calls your action

```
<apex:commandButton value="GO!" action="{!buttonGo}" />
```

And then in your controller, you can do something like this to send the user off to the relevant URL

```
public with sharing class testExtensions {

    public Test_Object__c tester { get; set; }

    public testExtensions(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.tester = (Test_Object__c)controller.getRecord();
    }

    public PageReference buttonGo()
    {
        PageReference pr = new PageReference('/' + String.valueOf(tester.Id).substring(0,3));
        pr.setRedirect(true);
        return pr;
    }

}
```

... You haven't said what is in your controller/what it does, so I can't speculate any better than that?? Hopefully this is enough to get your over the line though!